# combined local and remote journald logs

Tags: linux, systemd, journald, journalctl

I am using journald forwarding using `systemd-journal-remote` (local site) and `systemd-journal-upload` (remote site) on centos7 with systemd-219 on both machines.

Local journals are stored in `/var/log/journal/<machine_id>/*.journal` whereas remote uploads are stored in `/var/log/journal/remote/remote-*.journal`.

I'm able to view both seperatly using `journalctl -lf` or `journalctl -D /var/log/journal/remote -lf`.

I am now trying to get a combined view using `journalctl -m`, where the man page says that it would show entries [from all available journals, including remote ones](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html), but that doesn't seem to work, at least not the way I'd expect, because the journals aren't merged in any way.

Using `SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug journalctl -lfm` gives hints about the included journal files:

```
Root directory /var/log/journal added.
Considering /var/log/journal/fb643c7c40aa414aab4fe052ee7aff57.
Directory /var/log/journal/fb643c7c40aa414aab4fe052ee7aff57 added.
File /var/log/journal/fb643c7c40aa414aab4fe052ee7aff57/system.journal added.
File /var/log/journal/fb643c7c40aa414aab4fe052ee7aff57/user-1001.journal added.
File /var/log/journal/fb643c7c40aa414aab4fe052ee7aff57/user-1000.journal added.
Journal filter: none
Considering /var/log/journal/fb643c7c40aa414aab4fe052ee7aff57.
... journal output ...
```

Is there a way to achive a merged view of all journals, by which I mean all journal files located *somewhere* under `/var/log/journal/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix appears to be coming in https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/4970

Answer (score 1):

I can't find how to set other search path.

Workaround: override the systemd-journal-remote service where set the --output=/var/log/journal instead of /var/log/journal/remote/.

Don't forget take care proper permission settings.

Answer (score 0):

journalctl -mf
using -m for merge flag
(-m --merge)